# Python Markdown library that handles microdata

Tags: library, web-development, python

I host my own [Pelican](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/stable/) based static web page. I write my content in Markdown (not reStructuredText).

I am looking for a library that allows me to easily add [microdata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microdata_(HTML)) elements to my content. I've found what appears to be a [good plugin](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pelican-microdata) for reStructuredText content.

However, I'm looking for something that does that with Markdown based content. Converting my content from Markdown to reStructuredText isn't an option I'm considering at this point.

Criteria:

- Python based library that handles microdata within Markdown and converts to valid HTML
- Bonus if this is already a pelican plugin, but not a requirement

Comment: For what it's worth, reStructuredText is in general the more feature-rich of the two, so if you convert now, it will be easier to extend your site in other ways in the future. You may be able to convert from one to the other automatically with, e.g., Pandoc.